# Conditional grouping of Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas Data Frame like:

```
  ID  Group   Rank include 
  1   Group1  1    0     
  2   Group1  2    1     
  3   Group1  3    0     
  4   Group1  4    1     
  5   Group2  1    0     
  6   Group2  2    0     
  7   Group2  3    1    
  8   Group2  4    1     
  9   Group2  5    1
```

I want to select a subset that satisfies following conditions:
- max 3 rows from the group
- include all the rows that have include = 1  (there are no more than 3 per group)
- minimize the total rank per group

Basically, I want to select TOP "N" records from each group, but rows with include=1 have priority over the rest of them.

Output Data Frame:

```
  ID  Group   Rank include 
  1   Group1  1    0     
  2   Group1  2    1       
  4   Group1  4    1         
  7   Group2  3    1    
  8   Group2  4    1     
  9   Group2  5    1
```

I have tried several approaches, but none of them really worked, and now I am stuck.
Please help!

Answer (score 2):

First sort the dataframe by your conditions:

```
df.sort_values(['include', 'Rank'], ascending=[False, True], inplace=True)
```

Then groupby `Group` and get the top 3 rows for each Group. Also, add a `sort_values` to have the final dataframe be sorted on `Group` then on `Rank`, like so:

```
df.groupby('Group').head(3).sort_values(['Group', 'Rank'])
```

Output:

```
   ID   Group  Rank  include
0   1  Group1     1        0
1   2  Group1     2        1
3   4  Group1     4        1
6   7  Group2     3        1
7   8  Group2     4        1
8   9  Group2     5        1
```

Comment: Nice but I think you can skip the group sort as the groupby will handle that. And rank should come first huh?

Comment: I think you're right about removing the `Group` sort. Edited. I think OP's question gives more important to `include` than to `Rank`. Therefore, using that order.

Comment: Yep that might be right. Looke better now. The one-liner seems pointless though if you don't split it on multiple rows I'd say.

Comment: True. It just combines the above two lines. Removed it.